# Rails display results in form as text or labels instead of "text_field",allow destroy only, no updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, label, form-for, textfield

I would like to be able to create tags only, no editing, but allowing destroying. The tags are a partial on my Posts page. It works I just cant figure out how to put the result that is in a "text_field" into a label.

```
<%= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>

<div class="field">

<%= tag_form.text_field :tag %> #instead of this I want the result as the label for the destroy textbox.

<% unless tag_form.object.nil? || tag_form.object.new_record? %>

<%= tag_form.check_box :_destroy %>
</div>
<% else %>
CREATE NEW TAG
<% end %>


<% end %>
```

Comment: I believe this SO answer explains it the best: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15928777/4880924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<%= tag_form.label :tag, 'TAG LABEL HERE' %>
```

Comment: Just an fyi, it's best practice that your variable tag_form be called 'f' for field.

Comment: Thanks ericraio, I have done that but unfortunately I don't know how to use the value of the form field in place of 'TAG LABEL HERE'.

Comment: The string tag label here is the second argument for the method label which means you can pass in anything you want to show up for the label.

Comment: Here is some documentation for label as well.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label

Comment: I understand I can place anything in there, I would like to place in there the value that "<%= tag_form.text_field :tag %> has inside the generated input field that you see in the html. Is there an easy way to access that result for use in the label

Comment: Embarressing all I wanted was: <%= tag_form.object.tag %>

Comment: @user1055934 great that you found the answer. I would like to do the exact same thing that you are doing. In this case, what should the "object" be and what should the "tag" be? <%= tag_form.object.tag %> . your advice much appreciated - your answer will help thousands who are looking for the answer like  you once did.