# Display the value of a field using form builder into a label in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label

I am using Rails 3.2 and am in need to display the value of a field in a label using a form builder object. Displaying it in a text box is straight forward but I am not able to do it in a label. the code is something like this:

```
<%= f.label :key_name, "#{:key_name}"%>
<%= f.text_field :key_name %>
```

In the above f is my form builder and my model has a field called key_name. The second line works fine in which I display it inside a text field while the first line does not. How do I do it. The line above ends up displaying "Key Name" as the label while I want the value of key_name to be set as the value of the label eg. it should generate a html as  `<label>Description</label>` where 'Description' is the value of the `:key_name`.
I also then have to write a case statement upon the key_name which also does not work because I dont know how to extract the value from the `:keyname` field. something like this:

```
<% case :key_name %>
  <% when 'Description' %>
   ... do something
```

Comment: Can you add your `form` code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#{:key_name}` is going to evaluate to the string `':key_name'`, which is then what is being printed.  You need to call the *method* `key_name` on your model instance, like:

```
<%= f.label :key_name, @model.key_name %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. that worked. I did not know how to access the model through the form builder object but I found it out. I have written code like the below and its working fine. Thanks for your help:   <%= f.label :key_name, f.object.key_name %>

Answer (score 7):

To help anyone that would otherwise miss it. Here's OP's correct answer in the comments:

```
<%= f.label :key_name, f.object.key_name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same can be done with less code:

`<%= f.object.key_name %>`

unless insisted on the HTML label tag.